# Cómo se señala en el eje X la posición de las barras en un gráfico de barras en Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

estoy haciendo diversas pruebas con Python para representar datos. Y quiero leer de una hoja de excel una serie de datos para hacer un diagrama de barras. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

canales = pd.read_excel(miruta, sheet_name="hoja")

canal = canales.Canal
rep = canales.Repeticiones

channel = []
repet = []
for element in canal:
    channel.append(element)
for element in rep:
    repet.append(element)


x = np.array(channel)
y = np.array(repet)


plt.bar(x, y, align="center")
plt.xlabel("Canal")
plt.ylabel("Número de MACs captadas")
plt.show()
```

Con eso, consigo representar la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer ahora es marcar el número debajo de cada barra, es decir, las dos barras que no tienen marcado su correspondiente X (que sería 56 y 104) sí deberían tenerlo, y no sé cómo hacerlo. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Muchas gracias, muchachos

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `plt.xticks([40, 56, 60, 104])` para especificar los marcadores (ticks) en el eje x de forma manual. Puede inclusive especificar un valor personalizado con una segunda lista de la forma `plt.xticks([40, 56, 60, 104], ['CH1=40', 'CH2='56', 'CH3=60', 'CH4=104'])`